# Uploading error with nginx and thin server in Rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, timeout, paperclip, thin

I have deployed my app here http://jobmre.com/ with nginx and thin server.

When I tried to upload big mp4 files of size, say 100MB. I have an error as shown in screenshot

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Any help to resolve this issues.I am using paperclip for uploading.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your nginx server block and add this line

```
client_max_body_size 500M;
```

This will allow uploading of 500 megabytes, if you want more or less it's up to you.

Comment: "Edit your nginx server block mean" in what configuration file?

Comment: Well you tagged the question with nginx, where is you nginx config?